# how to know next random number?

Tags: javascript

i have a function

```
function randomgenerator()
{
r1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
document.getElementById("currentrandom").innerHTML = r1;
}
```

and two div id's

```
<div id = "first">0</div>
<div id = "second">0</div>
```

when a button is pressed i want to print generated random number in first div id which i have done. but i am not able to find logic to know what next random number will be so that i can print it in second div id. i want to print both the random number at the same time when a button is pressed. Is there any way please?

Comment: Erm - if you can guess the next random number it is no longer random - call the function twice and assign the results to each div. Also remove the quotes from "currentrandom" since it needs to be passed or a var - like this: https://jsfiddle.net/819sfyLj/

Comment: How do you want to know what the **next random** number is as it is a **random number**?

Comment: Just add r2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
document.getElementById("currentrandom").innerHTML = r2;, but there will never be any guessing, it is the purpose of random

Comment: Specify which PRNG in the question

Comment: Trying out my mind reader cap here – do you mean that you want to generate two random numbers, and when the button is pressed again you want to move the number from the second div to the first one and re-generate a new number for the second div?

Comment: Math.random() doesn't return a random number it retuns a pseudo-random number so there may be a platform dependent way to guess the number in advance.

Comment: To find the "next random number" you will have to *generate* that second random number (if you need to use it on another iteration or something, store it in a variable). Also a minor note, you don't actually have an element with id "currentrandom" in this snippet.

Comment: yes i was exactly trying to say that @Juhana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this (based on one of your comments)

```js
function randomgenerator() {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
}
var rnd = [0,randomgenerator()];
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("but").innerHTML = "Shift to "+rnd;
  document.getElementById("but").onclick=function() {
    document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = rnd[0];
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = rnd[1];
    rnd.unshift(randomgenerator());
    rnd.pop();
    document.getElementById("but").innerHTML = "Shift to "+rnd;
  }    
}
```

```html
<div id = "first">0</div>
<div id = "second">0</div>
<button type="button" id="but">
Shift 0,0
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function randomgenerator()     {
  r1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  document.getElementById("currentrandom").innerHTML = r1;
  r2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = r2;
}
```

(but you really need to explain to us how those 2 DIVs get populated, and what you mean by "currentrandom".)

If you didn't know - there is no such thing in javascript as random numbers - every random sequence is perfectly repeatable, so you can always know which number is going to be picked next.
Here is how to use that:-

```
Random generator = new Random(seed);
```

If you want to know what the second random number will be, first do the above, and get the second number, then do the above again, and you'll re-start the sequence. Choose something constant for the seed (or unpredictable if you want to pretend this is secure for some reason; keep in mind that random in javascript is never secure though, no matter what seed you pick; their Mersenne primes are too small.)

Comment: i was trying to say is i want to generate two random numbers, and when the button is pressed again i want to move the number from the second div to the first one and re-generate a new number for the second div @Anon Coward

Comment: Please update your answer instead of deleting and answering again.